# How to get photo bucket consumer key

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, api, apache-flex, photobucket

I have to use photo bucket api in one of my project. But i can't be able to get consumer key for it. I have already create developer account. But i can't go further without consumer key.
Can anyone tell me the way to get it and how to use it in photobucket. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"Our engineers are working on a new API, with lots of changes, however, this won't be available to users for a couple more months.... If you'd rather not wait for this updated API, and would like the current iteration now, please send an email to our API request email address with the following information ..."

So looks like now you can get more details and obtain keys using [this link](http://support.photobucket.com/hc/en-us/articles/200724164-API-Requests-and-Information)

And [here is](https://github.com/maschall/Photobucket.NET) a good piece of code which can help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

As I understand photobucket doesn't support any API from 2010 year.

All developer sub-domains not working.

Email pbdl-api@photobucket.com  that reuqest API key doesn't exists.